# How to invoke a new EC2 instance with existing IAM role? / JavaScript AWS SDK v3 - RunInstancesCommand

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js-v3

**How can I launch an EC2 instance with attached (existing) IAM Role in JavaScript?**

I know this question has been asked for other languages, but I couldn't find an example for JavaScript.

My JS Lambda code currently looks like:

```
const { EC2Client } = require( "@aws-sdk/client-ec2");
const ec2Client = new EC2Client({ region: "eu-central-1" }); 
const {
      CreateTagsCommand,
      RunInstancesCommand,
      TerminateInstancesCommand,
      RunInstancesRequest
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-ec2");      

const instanceParams = {
      ImageId: "ami-00a844bXXXXXXXXXX",
      InstanceType: "a1.xlarge",
      KeyName: "YourKeyName", 
      MinCount: 1,
      MaxCount: 1,
      SecurityGroupIds: ["sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
      IamInstanceProfile: "arn:aws:iam::390000000000:instance-profile/NAME" // doesn't work
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await ec2Client.send(new RunInstancesCommand(instanceParams));
    console.log(data.Instances[0].InstanceId);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
}

var ret = await run();
```

---

Documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ec2/interfaces/runinstancescommandinput.html#iaminstanceprofile

---

```
"@aws-sdk/client-ec2": "^3.44.0",
"@aws-sdk/client-lambda": "^3.45.0",
```

The code above runs, but the IAM Role under the EC2 > Instances > Security tab *remains empty in all my tries*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IamInstanceProfile field you need to specify the ARN or name. Try with any of these options:

```
const instanceParams = {
  ImageId: "ami-00a844bXXXXXXXXXX",
  InstanceType: "a1.xlarge",
  KeyName: "YourKeyName", 
  MinCount: 1,
  MaxCount: 1,
  SecurityGroupIds: ["sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
  IamInstanceProfile: 
  {
      Name: "NAME"
  }
};
```

or

```
    const instanceParams = {
  ImageId: "ami-00a844bXXXXXXXXXX",
  InstanceType: "a1.xlarge",
  KeyName: "YourKeyName", 
  MinCount: 1,
  MaxCount: 1,
  SecurityGroupIds: ["sg-XXXXXXXXXXXXX"],
  IamInstanceProfile: 
  {
      Arn: "arn:aws:iam::390000000000:instance-profile/NAME"
  }
};
```

---

[JavaScript SDK runInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#runInstances-property)

Comment: Thank you Omar! For those also having trouble here, you might afterwards get an error saying: "You are not authorized to perform this operation." - Which is duo to a missing Policy which you need to manually setup for "iam:PassRole"  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html